# RPi won't connect to ad-hoc

Tags: raspbian, networking, debian, wireless

As you see i'm newbie here.
I get a RPi, and i put raspbian in her, all work fine except internet that wan't connect .
The hotspot is an nokia mobile running JoikuSpot Lite that creates only Ad-hoc and no Infrastructure.

When i try to scan, works fine and show me the wireless point, but when i try add and connect just tell "Scanning" and no connect.

The program that i'm using in Raspbian is WiFi Config and one D-Link usb-adapter.

Comment: Will it connect to any wifi at all (besides the hotspot)?

Comment: Yes, i want to connect with an ad-hoc access point that i have.

Comment: I don't have a solution for you, but I can recommend looking up `Debian wireless troubleshooting`.  It will give you somewhere to start.  Good luck!

Comment: I can't see where i mark it.

Answer (score 2):

You must configure your wlan in ad-hoc mode, just type :

```
sudo -i
ifconfig wlan0 up
iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc
iwconfig wlan0 essid "YOUR_SSID"
ifconfig wlan0 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Do not forget to change YOUR_SSID with the name of your ad-hoc network.

To make these change permanent, just add these lines to `/etc/rc.local`